# Unable to register routes in SignalR 2.0.0

Tags: routes, signalr, owin

I decided to move to the latest version of signalr but i facing a few issues. First of all the way to register routes has entirely changed; so i tried to do it the way that this link http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes#TOC13 suggests.

The problem is that although i add

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="xxx.Startup, App_Code"/>
</appSettings>
```

to the web.config the `Configuration` is not invoked at all. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show more code.

Answer (score 5):

Solution !

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyNameSpace.Startup, MyNameSpace" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="Owin" verb="*" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the 2.0 beta working by

- Removing all references to the older version of SignalR, ie nuget uninstall of the library and double checking /bin
- Installed SignalR 2.0.0-beta2 via Package Manager Console `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre`
- Following the steps in the 1.x to 2.0 migration outlined in the ops [link](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes#TOC13)
- **And most importantly changing the project config to use Local IIS Web server instead of Visual Studio Developer Server (Cassini).**

More info in the question/answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959361/signalr-hubs-not-being-generated-when-upgrading-to-signalr-2-0-0-beta2/17959715#17959715)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer was that this DLL was missing:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll
```

It was omitted by my build process. It seems that it needs to be present in the `bin` folder of an Asp.Net site for the `Configuration` method to get called.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a website? If this is a website the assembly for the website is getting generated dynamically so you cannot figure out the fully qualified name of your startup class like this. Instead try adding an assembly level attribute in your code like this and see if your Startup.Configuration is invoked.

[assembly : OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

Comment: OwinStartup does not exist in beta 2

Answer (score 0):

By default it will search for a file called Startup; so the only thing i had to do was to create a Startup class under the `Assembly-name.Startup` namespace.

The namespace should follow the above pattern to make the it possible to find the startup class