# How to use signalr v2 beta in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, owin

Before v2:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

In v2, MapHubs does not exist anymore. The wiki says to add a Startup class and a Configuration method and a call to app.MapHubs().

```
namespace MyAssembly 
{
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //Before v2
        //RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        app.MapHubs();
    }
}
}
```

But the method is never called, no error occurs, and ... no hub are setup.

I suppose there is some code to add to global.asax.cs

What is the secret ?

Comment: Did you add anything to web.config?

Comment: no, nothing in web.config

Comment: Now they changed it to  app.MapSignalR();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: removed lines not relevant.

Solution !

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyNameSpace.Startup, MyNameSpace" />
</appSettings>
```

plus update both MVC4 (not to prerelease, but to latest stable version) and SignalR/owin nugets.

plus fix bugs in js client :

- if disconnectTimeout=999000 then it is disabled. Must be set server-side with: GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(999);
  note: server side can not set a value < 6 (signalr throws an exception if DisconnectTimeout < 6). So use this magic number.
- webSockets: set connection.socket = null in sockettransport, otherwise the call to start fails after a (manual) call to stop
- serverSentEvents: prevent error caused by a reconnection attempt when the window is unloading
- chrome fails with exception if signalr hub url not available (temporarily) : Instead of giving up  try the next available protocol / try to reconnect.

Comment: This works, ie Startup code is called, but sql backplane throws exception, and no mvc action can be reached. Maybe MVC5 prerelase package should be used.

Comment: You totally don't need any of that config you added. All you did was re-declare what all of the defaults are.

Comment: maybe, but it does nothing at all without.

Comment: It's likely because you didn't put the class in the right namespace.

Comment: and what would be the right namespace ? I hate magic. I do math not divination.

Comment: Post beta2 it throws a nice error telling you what to do. We didn't get to make the change for beta2. The "right" namespace is the one that's named after your assembly.

Comment: well i tryed again and it worked ok. The only diff is I updated MVC4 to latest stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining [assembly : OwinStartup(typeof(MyAssembly.Startup))] to see if your Startup class is being picked up.

Comment: OwinStartup doesn't exist in beta2.

Comment: Try adding the appSetting owin:AppStartup with value= fully qualified name of your startup class. For example "MyAssembly.Startup, MyAssembly"

Comment: already tryed, does nothing at all. It seems that signalr v2 targets VS2013/MVC5 only !

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613255/unable-to-register-routes-in-signalr-2-0-0?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the 2.0 beta working by

- Removing all references to the older version of SignalR, ie nuget uninstall of the library and double checking /bin
- Installed SignalR 2.0.0-beta2 via Package Manager Console `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre`
- Following the steps in the 1.x to 2.0 migration outlined [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes#TOC13)
- **And most importantly changing the project config to use Local IIS Web server instead of Visual Studio Developer Server (Cassini).**

More info in the question/answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959361/signalr-hubs-not-being-generated-when-upgrading-to-signalr-2-0-0-beta2/17959715#17959715)

Comment: Cassini has been replaced by IIS Express a long time ago. The web server should not be the problem here as SignalR works ok with any version, even if websockets are activated only on IIS 8.

Comment: @Softlion I'm using VS2012 and switching from dev server to local IIS fixed the error I was getting which was `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.`

Comment: Sure, but i do not have this error. I'll recheck in some days.

Answer (score 0):

In web.config there must be a fully qualified name of the class, e.g.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="**My.Name.Space.Startup**, **AssemblyName**" />
</appSettings>
```

I had a problem when I put namespace instead of assembly name, but with the fully qualified name it works without any other changes to web.config!

UPDATE: I also followed the steps from the link: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes#TOC13, i.e. removed a NuGet package "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin"

Comment: I will retry a 100th time, but i'm not a beginner. That did not work. Well that did work only to get http 500 errors without any trace / log which is bizarre.

Comment: @Softlion why don't you try the simplest chat example from the documentation in your existing assembly? if that will work you could rule out the assembly name issue and focus on other things http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting

Comment: @Softlion Have you removed a NuGet package "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin" as well? http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes#TOC13

Comment: well i tryed again and it worked ok. The only diff is I updated MVC4 to latest stable version.